# How can I open a php webpage with uiwebview?

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I'm trying to open/display the rssfeed http://www.golfweekly.nl/rss.php in a uiwebview. But the screen stays blank. Opening http://www.google.com will just show the google content.

This is how my WebView.m file is looking:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *strWebPage = @"http://www.golfweekly.nl/rss.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strWebPage];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webViewBuienRadar loadRequest:requestURL];
    [strWebPage release];   

}
```

After some very usefull tip/response it works with the following code :

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString * userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3";
    NSString * urlString = @"http://reader.mac.com/mobile/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.golfweekly.nl%2Frss.php";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [req setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    [webViewBuienRadar loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:URL];
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want your users to see?

Comment: Hi Ali, it will show a list with golfsport newsheaders. Clicking on a newsheader will show detailinformation. This is functionality of golfweekly. - Boudewijn.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287643/ios-uiwebview-of-rss-to-look-more-like-safari-and-stay-inside-app

Comment: did you check the error delegate method?

Comment: @user1268984 : thanks for reediting your question to post your answer. I believe this is your first post. Normally, what you have to do is choosing the question that lead you to the answer (by checking it). I don't know if you can post your own answer. If you can, do it and check it. Else, check the answer that helped you. Regards.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, This is my first post. I forgot to check the answers. I am really suprised by the quick response and help. I hope I can give some answers too in the future to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, refer to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287643/ios-uiwebview-of-rss-to-look-more-like-safari-and-stay-inside-app) where you can find a suggestion allowing you to parse the incoming rss feed as the `UIWebview` wouldn't not display it.

Another nice solution there allows you to change your User Agent.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, I quickly copy/paste/edit the code from the post into my file and it works directtly !!! Little by little I get understand the parsing need.

Comment: Thank you all for responding this quickly.

Comment: In the post i do not exactly understand the line userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"; Is this a correct line ?

Comment: @user1268984 : Yes, this is the user agent. You are just telling to the website (the yours) that you are connecting from the safari mobile  version.

Comment: OK, thank you for confirmation. I'll read about useragents myself.

Answer (score 3):

Your URL above serves an RSS and not a HTML page. Main desktop browsers like firefox, ie, etc. have a feature to parse the RSS and render it to a user-readable form. UIWebView does not have this feature as far as I know thus it can not load the page. You will need to parse the RSS file yourself and generate a HTML page (or even table view contents, etc) based on it.